# Redshift | Copy Command

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm importing some rows from a MySql environment to Redshift. In the process I convert it into a csv (using pandas), place it in S3 and from there run a COPY command into Redshift.

I notice though that sometimes some of the whole numbers get converted into float:

```
EG: 1234 -> 1234.0
```

The problem with this is when doing the COPY command the column is of type BIGINT and not FLOAT, so I get an error type:

```
Invalid digit, Value '.', Pos 7, Type: Long                                                         
1695111.0
```

I know I can CAST it to be of type BIGINT, but the function that is doing the extraction has to be dynamic and I can't do explicit changes to columns like that. The main reason is that I'm doing an extract all with `SELECT * FROM table` in numerous tables, tagging a specific column will be difficult and time consuming.

My work-around has been to change the column to float, but ideally I want to keep them as int. Maybe there's a functionality within the COPY command that just follows the data type of the target column rather than going based of the source?

Any ideas?

COPY function just in case:

```
COPY "{kwargs['schema']}".{kwargs['table_qa']} ({col_names})
FROM 's3://{kwargs['bucket']}/{kwargs['csv_name']}'
WITH CREDENTIALS {S3_KEY}
CSV
FILLRECORD
IGNOREHEADER {kwargs['ignore_header']}
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like your CSV-generation process is adding the decimals? Is there any way to stop that from happening?

Comment: You need to the fix the CSV export process, not the CSV loading process.

Comment: Is there a way to have the CSV get generated and respect the numeric format? That could be an option since the query does pass int and when it gets appended to the CSV, the extra decimals get added.